# Best practise for integration of Google's Web Starter Kit with AppEngine/Jinja2

Tags: google-app-engine, frameworks, jinja2

Google released the great [Web Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/starter-kit/) a while ago and I was just wondering if anyone has used it in combination with AppEngine and/or Jinja2? I am not quite sure what the best practise is for using Web Starter Kit in AppEngine.

I guess one possibility would be to develop the base layout template and stylesheets according the [Web Starter Kit build process](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/tools/build/build_process#whats-in-the-web-starter-kit-build-process). Once the base layout has been finished, html and css files could be copied into the AppEngine project into the appropriate (static) folders. From there one could work on individual Jinja2 templates that extend the base template. The only pain is that changes to both CSS, images and the base template would always have to be copied over into their Jinja2/AppEngine directories.

Does anyone have a better idea in working with AppEngine, Jinja2 and the Web Starter Kit in a efficient way?

---

A few minutes and experiments later I created a `html_frontend` folder within the root directory. In that folder I am storing both `app` (contains the original html files) and `dist` (contains minimalised files). While I am developing in within `app`, I link static files and templates to the `app` directory. Also in my versioning control I am only checking in `app` as it contains the original files that can be used to compute the entire file and folder structure within `dist`. I am not sure yet though how to prevent AppEngine from uploading/deploying both `app` and `dist`.

---

The `app.yaml` would then look as follows:

```
- url: /styles
  static_dir: html_frontend/dist/styles
- url: /fonts
  static_dir: html_frontend/dist/fonts
```

---

This is how I eventually made it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24892700/3628578

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing around for a bit, I found *one* way of integrating the Web Starter Kit into a Python AppEngine and Jinja2 project. I am sure it is not *the* perfect way of doing this, but it seems to be working quite well. Here is a short description of how I did it.

1. Install and configure all packages and programs as described here:
   https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/tools/index?hl=en
2. Copy all files into your template folder within your AppEngine project, e.g. `html_frontend`.
3. Adjust your `app.yaml` to ensure that all files can be served properly by the web-server.

   First, the handlers should be extended somehow like this (if you copied to a different directory than `html_frontend` you should remember to adjust the paths):

   ```
   - url: /fonts
     static_dir: html_frontend/dist/fonts
   - url: /images
     static_dir: html_frontend/dist/images
   - url: /scripts
     static_dir: html_frontend/dist/scripts
   - url: /styles
     static_dir: html_frontend/dist/styles
   ```

   Then, certain files and folders should be 'skipped', i.e. prevented from uploading to AppEngine. Do this simply by adding this to the end of your `app.yaml`:

   ```
   skip_files:
   - ^html_frontend/app
   - ^html_frontend/node_modules
   - ^html_frontend/.sass-cache
   ```
4. While we are adjusting config files, add the following lines into your `.hgignore` to prevent
   Mercurial from commiting too many files (or if you use a different version control system, you should find out how to ignore the files and folders there):

   ```
   html_frontend/.sass-cache
   html_frontend/node_modules
   html_frontend/dist
   ```
5. Create your HTML files always within `html_frontend/app`. From there you can create new Jinja2 templates that, for example, extend a base template. Changes to the CSS can be made by editing the SASS files (stored in `styles/components`) or the `main.css` file. But always remember: always edit files within `html_frontend/app`.
6. Compile your changes: open a terminal window within `html_frontend` and run the command `gulp` as described in the Web Starter Kit documentation.You will notice that a folder named `dist` will be created which contains all HTML, CSS and JS files but minimised.
7. To ensure that Python and Jinja2 can find the templates, you configure the correct path:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_PATH = "html_frontend/dist"
   ```
8. Follow the Web Starter Kit styleguide to build the best-looking webpage.
9. Have fun!

Comment: Good answer. I like your directory structure; it's less spammy to the root.

Answer (score 0):

I use git and appengine [push to deploy](https://developers.google.com/cloud/devtools/repo/cloud-repositories). In a git repository you can use a .gitignore

Example: https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/.gitignore

Comment: Thank you for that, it's not quite what I meant. I was more wondering about best practises of using the Web Starter Kit within a Python AppEngine and Jinja2 application. But I think I have figured that one out now. I will post a solution soon.